# i want to display the values depending on the ID passing in the URl

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

I want to display the database values depending on the particular ID. I pass that id in the URL, and it redirects to another page with ID. In that page I have to display that particular user's records.

Here is the controller function:

```
public function consultants()
{
    return view('Hr/view-request-candidates', [
        'consultant' => HrRequestConsultant::all(),
    ]);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get(
    '/view-request-candidates/{hr_request_id}',
    'Hr\HrDashboardController@consultants'
);
```

URL:

```
<a href="/view-request-candidates/{{$row->id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">CANDIDATES</a>
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Hr Request ID</th>
        <th>Consultant ID</th>
        <th>No Of Candidates</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>

  @foreach($consultant as $row)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$row->hr_request_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->consultant_id}}</td>
        <td>{{30}}</td>

        <td>
          <a href="/view-hr-candidates" class="btn btn-primary">View</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
  @endforeach
```

How can I do this?

Comment: after routes declare You can get the id in public function consultants($Id) like this and then you can fetch the data in controller directly based on id nad redirect then another page with this $id variable which you used in <a> </a>  tag.

Comment: so i dont need to pass id in routes right? if i didnt pass it will produce error

Comment: No you have to pass id in routes as well as in controller public function consultants ( $id ) like this .. then you logic is here to fetch the data based on this id from the database and then after you redirect to view .

Comment: public function consultants($id)
    {
        return view('Hr/view-request-candidates', [
            'consultant' => HrRequestConsultant::all(),
        ]);
    }

Comment: but it displaying all the values..not particular record..

Comment: bcoz u used all ..

Comment: yes..can you please tell me how can we do that..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142325/discussion-between-rishikesh-kumar-and-bharathi).

Comment: hello.... got it... r u there ??

Answer (score 1):

**Routes::**

```
Route::get('home','HrDashboardController@home');

Route::get('view-hr-candidates/{hr_request_id}','HrDashboardController@consultants');
```

**Controller::**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\HrRequestConsultant;
use DB;
class HrDashboardController extends Controller
{ 


   public function home(){  
   $home = HrRequestConsultant::select('id','hr_request_id','consultant_id')->get();
   return view('home')->with('home', $home); 

   //Its View:  home.blade.php file

 }


   public function consultants($id){ 

   $result = HrRequestConsultant::select('id','hr_request_id','consultant_id')->where('hr_request_id',$id)->first(); 

   return $returnview = view('Hr.view-request-candidates')->with('result', $result); 
     // Its view-request-candidates.blade.php file InSide the Hr Dir.  
   }

}
```

**home.blade.php::**

```
<body>
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title m-b-md">  View Details  </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">

                  <table border="1" style='color: black'>

                <tr>
                <th>Hr Request ID</th>
                <th>Consultant ID</th> 
                <th>No Of Candidates</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
               </tr>

           @foreach ($home as $data){
                <tr>
                <td> {{ $data['hr_request_id'] }} </td>
                <td> {{ $data['consultant_id'] }} </td>
                <td> 30 </td>
                <td> <a href="view-hr-candidates/{{ $data['hr_request_id'] }}" class="btn btn-primary">View</a> </td>
               </tr>
            @endforeach

               </table>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**view-request-candidates.blade.php**

```
<h1> Hello .. This Is Request Id:   {{ $result['hr_request_id'] }} </h1>
<br>
<h1> Hello .. This Is Consultant Id: {{ $result['consultant_id'] }} </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the single record use the `find` method instead of `all`:

```
public function consultants($id)
{
    return view('Hr/view-request-candidates', [
        'consultant' => HrRequestConsultant::find($id),
    ]);
}
```

It is best practice to name the route and use name wherever you need that route. So change the route like this :

```
Route::get(
'/view-request-candidates/{hr_request_id}',
'Hr\HrDashboardController@consultants')->name('view.consultant');
```

Remove the `foreach` loop from your view and change the route to named route:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Hr Request ID</th>
            <th>Consultant ID</th>
            <th>No Of Candidates</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$consultant->hr_request_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$consultant->consultant_id}}</td>
                <td>{{30}}</td>

                <td>
                   <a href="{{ route('view.consultant', ['hr_request_id' => $consultant->hr_request_id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">View</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']' (View: /home/gtpl/workspace/glob_hire/resources/views/Hr/view-request-candidates.blade.php)

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: You don't have consultant with specified ID in your database